# SQL Server related time range issues

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have an hour-by-hour database for N years. I want to extract a period of time in each year. For example, `2-3 21:00:00` to `5-12 09:00:00`.

I want to query all the data in this time period for all the years at once. Is there a way to do this?

The table format is similar to this：

| ID | SID | TT | BC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 55555 | 2007-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 22 12 18 20 |
| 2 | 55555 | 2007-01-01 01:00:00.000 | 22 12 18 20 |
| 3 | 55555 | 2009-02-01 01:00:00.000 | 22 12 18 20 |
| 4 | 55555 | 2009-03-21 20:00:00.000 | 22 12 18 20 |
| 5 | 55555 | 2011-04-02 23:00:00.000 | 22 12 18 20 |
| 6 | 55555 | 2012-07-05 01:00:00.000 | 11 65 10 61 |
| 7 | 55555 | 2013-08-01 02:00:00.000 | 16 20 6 16 |

SQL Server seems to be limited to a year, month, day, or hour range. Trying to limit it with functions like MONTH or DAY doesn't give the desired result. It does work if you use a loop, but I'm still wondering if I can use some special way of solving this problem using only SQL set operation. Any ideas are appreciated. How can I do this?

Comment: Please [create an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with desired results e.g. at [dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/ER_9PaV-).

Comment: What does "2-3 21:00:00" mean? The 2nd to 3rd month at exactly 21:00? 21:00 on the 2nd day of the year to 21:00 on the 3rd day of the year? Something else?

Comment: You know SQL Server 2012 is fully end-of-life, right? That it hasn't received any updates -- not even critical security patches! -- in over a year, and there are known vulnerabilities with a CVSSV3.0 score of 9.8 (critical!) that will _never_ be patched. It's dangerous and irresponsible to still be using it. 2016 is minimum safe version at the moment.

Comment: @汤姆·A    Sorry, maybe I didn't express myself clearly enough.
2-3 21:00:00 to 5-12 09:00:00
It refers to the period from February 3 21:00 to May 12 09:00, all years included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no good way to do this, where "good" is defined as "not needing a separate calculation for every row in the table", but at least it's possible.

Anyway, what I would do is use the default/0 year of 1900 to provide the target month/day/time value as a full datetime. Assuming the Month-Day ordering of the samples, that would look like this in code: `19000203 21:00:00` and `19000512 09:00:00` (for historical reasons, it's safer in SQL Server to use the unseparated ISO-8601 variant for dates).

Then I would transform the values for each record like this to match the year in each row:

```
DATEADD(Year, Year(TT)-1900, '19000203 21:00:00')
DATEADD(Year, Year(TT)-1900, '19000512 09:00:00')
```

So you can do a direct comparison:

```
SELECT *
FROM <table>
WHERE   TT >= DATEADD(Year, Year(TT)-1900, '19000203 21:00:00')
    AND TT <  DATEADD(Year, Year(TT)-1900, '19000512 09:00:00')
```

Again, I used 1900 because that's the epoch year for SQL Server, but other values can work as well. This isn't the fastest thing in the world, because you need to make a new calculation on each row, which probably also eliminates any index use, but at least it gives good results.

See it work here:

> https://dbfiddle.uk/t1hR5MAd

Comment: I would dispute your claim *there's no good way to do this, where "good" is defined as "not needing a separate calculation for every row in the table"* you can calculate a date range for each year separately and join it back

Comment: Thank you very much, you have solved my problem by suggesting this method.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do that is probably to construct a (possibly virtual) table of all the date ranges you want. For example, you can use `GENERATE_SERIES` or a `VALUES` constructor to generate the years, then calculate the dates off that.

```sql
SELECT
  t.*
FROM (VALUES
    (2020),
    (2021),
    (2022),
    (2023)
) AS v1(Year)
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
      StartDate = DATETIMEFROMPARTS(v1.Year, 2,  3, 21, 0, 0),
      EndDate   = DATETIMEFROMPARTS(v1.Year, 5, 12, 9,  0, 0)
) AS v2
JOIN YourTable t
  ON t.TT >= v2.StartDate
 AND t.TT < v2.EndDate;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/t1FRqIlf)

Comment: Thanks, I have considered this method you suggested, but I have multiple tables of this type and they all have variable date ranges (could be a few years more or fewer), so this method you suggested is not a good solution to my problem, but thank you for your help!

Comment: You could use a Table Valued Parameter or possibly a calendar table.

Comment: Okay, I may need to go down and look into that.